# In the armpit or under the armpit?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Which is the right thing to say?

> 1. Put the thermometer **in** the armpit.
> 2. Put the thermometer **under** the armpit.
> 3. Put the thermometer **under the arm**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word *[armpit](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/armpit?q=armpit)* is defined as "*a hollow under the arm at the shoulder*" and therefore I would go with option 1: "*Put the thermometer in the armpit.*" as I strongly believe we put something in a hollow rather than under it, though the expression "*under the armpit*" is still quite common, probably because many people visualize armpit as "*the joint where the arm connects to the shoulder*", and thus I don't consider "*under the armpit*" ungrammatical but technically speaking we don't put things *under* a hollow.

[image: Goolge Ngram]

The expression "*under the arm*" is grammatical but it describes a less precise location as the [arm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arm) is defined to be "*the part of the upper limb between the shoulder and the elbow joints*". Nevertheless, I think people would know which region "*under the arm*" you are talking about when thermometer is mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

You could use *under the axilla*.

Comment: The first two answers have already begin given, leaving "under the axilla."